# How to prove that only one circle can be inscribed inside a triangle in such a way that it touches all three sides?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I am trying to prove that there can be only one circle inscribed in a triangle such that it touches all three sides.
One way of doing this I think is by proving that the centre of a circle that touches all the sides of a triangle is the point of concurrence of the angle bisectors of the triangle.    And since there can be only one point of concurrence, there will be only one centre, and thus only one circle can be drawn.

But I am looking for a method that uses the properties of circles and tangents. Is there a proof that exists along these lines?

Comment: In my opinion it is correct and we use many tools here: Similar triangles, Angle bisector theorem, Ceva theorem...

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thank you so much! The answer did help for the first part of the question:) I have edited it now.

Answer (score -1):

**Theorem:** There is *one and only one circle* passing through *three given non-collinear points.*

Given: Three non collinear points (since a triangle is made up of three non-collinear points) that is A, B and C.

To Prove: There is one and only one circle passing through the points A, B and C.

Construction: As we have marked three non-collinear points in circle. Now, let’s join AB and BC. Then, Draw the perpendicular bisectors of RS and PQ of the chords AB and BC respectively as shown in figure.

Proof:

The point O lies on the perpendicular bisector of AB.
Therefore, OA = OB
And also, O lies on the perpendicular bisector of BC.
Therefore, OB = OC
Thus, we can say from above OA = OB = OC = r (where r stands for radius of the circle).
By taking O as the centre, construct a circle of radius r C(0,r) which passes through the points A, B and C.
Let us suppose there is another circle with the centre O’ and radius r, passing through the A, B and C. Then O’ will also lie on the perpendicular bisector of PQ and RS.
As we know that, the two lines cannot intersect at more than one point. So, O’ must coincide with O. Hence, there is one and only one circle passing through three non collinear points that are A, B and C.

[image]

Comment: Umm.. I was talking about a circle inside a triangle touching all the sides of the triangle and not a circle that passes through the points of the triangle